# How to prepopulate react form input fields using redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

What I am using :

1. redux-form@7.4.2
2. react-redux@5.0.7
3. redux@4.0.0
4. react@16.4.1

I am trying to implement an update form with the stack mentioned above and I want to prepopulate the form fields with Redux data. Redux form is set up and working okay. I can't prepopulate the fields though.

My question is : How redux does the connection between Fields and initialState data in order to fill the right input fields with the right data?

I have seen the example below but I haven't figured out the way things are working.

[Redux Form Prepopulate from initial State](https://codesandbox.io/s/4r22k345o0)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The connection is made by `name` property in the `Field` component. So:

```
// your initialValues
{
   name: 'Tom',
   surname: 'Rossi'
}

// your component
<Field
   name: 'name'
   ...
/>

<Field
   name: 'surname'
   ...
/>
```